# IApplicationBuilder exists in both Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions and Microsoft.AspNet.Http

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, roslyn

We're muddling thru doing authentication in ASP.NET 5. [In this security sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/79b190288e115d10ecf3f0b3598250a5489a063d/samples/SocialSample/Startup.cs#L197-L200), we see this type of thing:

```
app.Run(async context =>
{    
    var types = context.Authentication.GetAuthenticationSchemes();
}
```

## Initial Problem

In our project, however, the `HttpContext` did not have an `Authentication` property and we would receive the following error:

> Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn.RoslynCompilationException: C:\myApp\Startup.cs(71,46): error CS1061:
>
> 'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Authentication' and no extension method 'Authentication' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So, we looked at the source and found that its [here inside the `HttpAbstractions` assembly](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/6407a1672d92d89c4140fd1e5c07052599d4b97e/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions/HttpContext.cs#L23). So, we added that assembly to our project.

## Subsequent Problem

Unfortunately, we now receive the following error:

> Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn.RoslynCompilationException: C:\myApp\Startup.cs(43,31): error CS0433:
>
> The type 'IApplicationBuilder' exists in both 'Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'Microsoft.AspNet.Http, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

## Question

Fair enough. How can we ask the compiler to use the one assembly but not the other for this particular type? We've tried deleting `.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Http` but it just comes back after `dnu restore`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've probably "crossed the streams", as is being said by the ASP.NET teams. Make sure you're [following the breaking changes](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues) and aren't including packages from multiple `beta` versions (make sure you don't have both `beta4` and `beta5` referenced, for example - easiest way to check is search your project.lock.json for them.)  The most common accidents come from using `.Interfaces` packages as most of those have been renamed to `.Abstractions`, but there have been other assembly naming changes (and removals, too!).

## Update:

This error can also come up when you can't reach the NuGet packages via the servers you have configured and for the `dnvm` version you are running. (There was an update recently to `dnvm` that I had to upgrade in order to use the latest packages; seems that even within a single beta number the streams can still get crossed!)  To get VS2015 to use a specific `dnvm`, a `global.json` may be required:

```
{
    "projects": [ "src", "tests" ],
    "sdk": {
        "version": "1.0.0-beta6-12005"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my current project.json.lock: https://github.com/bigfont/mylocal-farm/blob/auth/myLocalFarm/src/farmApi/project.lock.json

Comment: I'm not sure how to make sure we don't have both `beta4` and `beta5` referenced. We've tried removing all references to `beta4` from our project.json, and we're continuing to experience the same problem.

Comment: When you say, "make sure you don't have both `beta4` and `beta5` referenced, to which dependencies are you referring? That is, `beta4` and `beta5` versions of which packages?  I'm not sure what packages we need to check to make sure we're not crossing the streams.

Answer (score 1):

Matt DeKrey was right. I needed not to cross the streams. In short, I needed `beta6` and was on `beta4`. Here were the steps to fix:

## 1 Change project.json

It now looks like this

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta6",
    "EntityFramework.InMemory": "7.0.0-beta6",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity": "3.0.0-beta6"
  }
```

## 2 Add a [Nuget.config](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file)

Importantly, I needed to add a Nuget.config file to the root of my repository, because `beta6` is not in NuGet yet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2" />
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

The `AspNetVNext` entry is the `Default Unstable` that we see when we run `dnvm`.

Comment: Looks like I'm in a much different time zone than you or I would have gotten back to your questions - glad you got it worked out!  (The project.lock.json shows the dependency tree, so you could have searched for `beta4` and found what was depending on it. But it's not a fun format to just go browse.)